Polynomial reduction function for languages in NPC, reduction from DHP to given language
Given language:
$L = {\{\langle G, e\rangle \mid G = (V, E)} \text{ a graph that contains a directed Hamiltonian path}$
$\text{that passes through edge } e \in E\}$
I want to show $DHP \leq_p L$.
Meaning to show reduction function from DHP to L that runs in polynomial time.
DHP defined as:
$\text{DHP} = \left\{ \langle G \rangle \mid \text{G is a directed graph containing a simple path} \right. \\
\left. \text{that passes through every vertex exactly once} \right\}
$
When given input $<G>$ to $f$ and i want to build the output $<G',e>$, so I thought of taking the graph $G$, and adding to the graph $2$ new vertexes: $u, v$.
And then also add edge $e$ that connects between them, and this will be $G'$.
Then, in order to make sure that $u, v$ and edge $e$ will be connected to the Hamilton path exist in $G$, I'll connect both $u$ and $v$ to each one of the vertexes currently exist in $V$ of $G$, with an edge for each direction.
This way, I'm assuring that i connected $u$ and $v$ to the begging and the end of the Hamilton path in $G$, and also the direction of the original Hamilton path wouldn't matter, because i connected $u$ and $v$ to the other vertexes with an edge for each direction (meaning two directional edge).
In fact, I get a Hamilton circle now in $G'$.
My problem is - I can't tell for sure if e should be defined as $e=(u,v)$ or $e=(v,u)$, because in order to get pass through it in the circle i created in $G'$, i need to know the direction of the original Hamilton path.
Someone has an idea how to solve it?
Or a different idea for how to build the reduction function?

Why not simply do the following. Given the graph $G=(V,E)$, the reduction outptus the same graph with additional new vertices $u$ and $v$, as you suggested, and then adds the following new directed edges: the edge $(u, v)$, and the edges $(v,s)$ for all $s\in V$. The edge $e$ will be $(u,v)$. Denote the output graph by $G'$.
Correctness is immediate as you can add $(u,v)$ to the beginning of every hampath in $G$ to get a hampath that passes through $e$ in $G'$. Conversely, if there is hampath $p'$ in $G'$, then it must start by traversing the edge $e$ first as $u$ has no incoming edges, and then $p'$ must follow a hampath in $G$.
